# Copying folders from one drive to another - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have two external hard drives(g & h). I want to copy one folder on g:(incl contents) to a folder on h.
I am using `copy-item g:\Folder1\* h:\Folder2`
I get the error msg *a positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument...*. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify which files are you going to copy. For example if you want to select all the content from `G:\Folder1` execute you can `Get-ChildItem "$files"`, store them in a variable then use it as parameter

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "G:\Folder1"
Copy-Item $files "h:\yourFolder"
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 1st time I've ever used Powershell. I've entered this line  C:\> $files = get-childitem "C:\Powershell_Source" copy-item $files c:\Powershell_Destination. I get this error msg-> S C:\> $files = get-childitem "C:\Powershell_Source" copy-item $files c:\Powershell_Destination

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem.

**-Recurse:** Copies the contents of the source directory and its subdirectories.

**-Force:** Overrides restrictions that prevent the command from succeeding, such as permissions.

```
Copy-Item -Path G:\YourSourceFolder -Destination H:\YourDestinationFolder -Recurse -Force
```